# Validating requests in PHP

Tags: php, html, validation, input, python-requests

Hey guys having trouble understanding how to validate requests using PHP and using else/if statements to get what I need from my coding. I need the code to display an active error message if a user fails to input information in any three fields in my HTML file. Currently my code for validating the requests rest like this:

```
enter code <?php
    $firstName = $_POST['firstName'];
    $phone = $_POST['phone'];       
    $numTickets = $_POST['numTickets'];
    $cost = $numTickets * 35.00;

    $ticketFile = fopen ("ticket-count.txt", "r");
    $totalTickets = fgets($ticketFile);
    fclose ($ticketFile);
        
    
    if (empty($firstName) OR  empty($phone) OR empty($numTickets) )
        print("ERROR: Input is missing!!");

    $availableSeats = 100 - (int)$totalTickets;
    if ($availableSeats < $numTickets) 
    {
        
        if ($availableSeats < 0) 
        {
            $availableSeats = 0;
            print ("<h1>Ticket Purchase</h1>");
            print ("<p>We are sorry. There are $availableSeats tickets available.  We 
                apologize for this inconvenience.</p>");
        }
        
        else
        {
            print ("<h1>Ticket Purchase</h1>");
            print ("<p>We are sorry. There are only $availableSeats tickets available.  Please 
                return to the form using the link below to change your order.</p>");
            print("<p><a href='event.html'>Click here to retun to order form</a></p>");

        }
    }
    else
    {
        print ("<h1>Ticket Purchase</h1>");
        print ("<p>Hi $firstName, You purchased $numTickets tickets. Your cost is $$cost. If we need to contact you we will call you at $phone.</p>");  
        
        $totalTickets = (int)$totalTickets + (int)$numTickets;
        
        $ticketFile = fopen ("ticket-count.txt", "w");
        fputs($ticketFile, "$totalTickets\n" );
        fclose ($ticketFile);
    }
    
    



?>here
```

Now I know the general idea as my code sits it does produce an error; however it still displays the additional information. For instance if I do not input any information in the "firstname" field it shows all the way up top "ERROR: Input is missing!" and then proceeds to display the phone field and number of tickets field.

Any help is appreciated. I feel like I've read over my book a thousand times and I attempted to use youtube etc, but am having trouble truly understanding.
Thanks again for any input!

HTML as requested:

```
enter code<h1>The Rolling Stones!</h1>
<p>In concert on January 15, 2011. Don't miss this great performance!</p>
<h2>To Purchase Tickets</h2>
<form action = "event.php" method = "post">
<table>
<tr><td>What is your First Name:</td><td><input type = "text" size = "20" name = "firstName"></td><tr>
<tr><td>And your Phone Number?</td><td><input type = "text" size = "20" name = "phone"></td><tr>
<tr><td>How many Tickets do you need?</td><td><input type = "text" size = "20" name = "numTickets"></td><tr>
</table>
<p><input type = "submit" value = "Submit Your Order"></p>
</form>
```

here

Comment: _"For instance if I do not input any information in the "firstname" field it shows all the way up top "ERROR: Input is missing!" and then proceeds to display the phone field and number of tickets field."_ So what's the problem? What do you want it to do instead? Also, please provide your HTML.

Comment: The issue is that I need my PHP to have the HTML display the error only. So for instance if I were to leave the "firstname" field blank and still fill the other fields, I need it to produce the error indicated only. Currently I have it producing the error alongside providing the values of $phone and $numTickets. I can upload the full PHP if needed as well. I'm just confused on whether my nesting is wrong or the validating itself is wrong.

Comment: I solved it! Thanks guys :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    $firstName = $_POST['firstName'];
    $phone = $_POST['phone'];       
    $numTickets = $_POST['numTickets'];
    $cost = (int)$numTickets * 35.00;

    if (empty($firstName) OR  empty($phone) OR empty($numTickets) )
        print("ERROR: Input is missing!!");
    elseif ( !is_numeric($phone) OR !is_numeric($numTickets) )
        print("ERROR: Non-numeric input found!");
    
    else
    {

    
    $ticketFile = fopen ("ticket-count.txt", "r");
    $totalTickets = fgets($ticketFile);
    fclose ($ticketFile);
        
    

    $availableSeats = 100 - (int)$totalTickets;
    if ($availableSeats < $numTickets) 
    {
        
        if ($availableSeats < 0) 
        {
            $availableSeats = 0;
            print ("<h1>Ticket Purchase</h1>");
            print ("<p>We are sorry. There are $availableSeats tickets available.  We 
                apologize for this inconvenience.</p>");
        }
        
        else
        {
            print ("<h1>Ticket Purchase</h1>");
            print ("<p>We are sorry. There are only $availableSeats tickets available.  Please 
                return to the form using the link below to change your order.</p>");
            print("<p><a href='event.html'>Click here to retun to order form</a></p>");

        }
    }
    else
    {
        print ("<h1>Ticket Purchase</h1>");
        print ("<p>Hi $firstName, You purchased $numTickets tickets. Your cost is $$cost. If we need to contact you we will call you at $phone.</p>");  
        
        $totalTickets = (int)$totalTickets + (int)$numTickets;
        
        $ticketFile = fopen ("ticket-count.txt", "w");
        fputs($ticketFile, "$totalTickets\n" );
        fclose ($ticketFile);
    }
    
    }



?>
```